# "How much do you pay" vs "How much you pay"

Tags: difference

> How much do you pay for it?
> How much you pay/paid for it?

What's the difference between the two ?

Comment: Welcome to ELL!  Please share what research you have already done, and what you found that confused you.  What do you think the answer might be?  (To improve your question, use the **[Edit]** button on your question and add details, please.)  Please read the "[Contributor's Guide to ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide)" and [Details Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/details-please).  Keep contributing and welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**How much do you pay for it?** is grammatically correct, though you'd rather say **How much did you pay for it?** as it refers to an action that obviously happened in the past.

**How much you pay/paid** is not grammatical unless used as a question word clause like **Tell me how much you paid for it.**